# Set static background image size in css when we minimize or maximize the site the image can't change?

Tags: css

```
.image {
    background-image: url('task pic 1.jpeg'), url('task pic 2.jpeg'), url('task pic 3.jpeg');
    background-position: left bottom, left top, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: -200px;
    margin-left: 800px;
    padding: 300px;
    border: 100%;
    width: auto;
    background-size: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: anyone know about this?

Comment: Can you share screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a static width/height using `background-size`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('https://www.enterprise.ca/content/dam/ecom/general/Homepage/inspiration-banff-ca.jpg.wrend.1280.720.jpeg'), url('https://www.enterprise.ca/content/dam/ecom/general/Homepage/inspiration-banff-ca.jpg.wrend.1280.720.jpeg'), url('https://www.enterprise.ca/content/dam/ecom/general/Homepage/inspiration-banff-ca.jpg.wrend.1280.720.jpeg');
  background-position: 0 0, 0 200px, 100px 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: Hii Danial thanks for replying me but i want multiple images in my window (i share my screen shot) and then i min/maximize then size can't change..

Comment: DniEl yoy are right but my task is like (you see my chrome screen) i want this type of image frame...]

Comment: Just change your `background-size` property to a static value and it will work

Comment: If your container has a dynamic width/height then it won't work

Comment: You can use static positioning to fix this, check my edit

Comment: after that you minimize the screen you see likr nothind will change.....

Comment: i want images windows right(you can see my screenshot) side...

Comment: I only positioned it there for the snippet, you can add you margin and padding back to position it how you want

Comment: bro i mean image size can't change

Comment: The image sizes don't change

Comment: bro i mean background -size

Comment: bro the background-size doesn't change. What *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: Hii Daniel last problem is solved you see i post answer code..Tx for helping...!!!

Answer (score 0):

body{margin: 0;}
.image{
background-image: url('task pic 1.jpeg'),url('task pic 2.jpeg'),url('task pic 3.jpeg');
padding:20%;
background-position: 80% 0%,80% 90%,100% 50%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:auto;
background-size:20%;
position: relative;
}